# Salir de bucles do while anidados en java

Tags: java, while

tengo la siguiente estructura:

```
do{
    do{
        if(){
        }
    }while(); 
}while();
```

Todo ello dentro de un método. Si la condicion del if se cumple, quiero salir de los 2 bucles do while, pero continuar en la funcion. He probado con return pero se sale de la funcion.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta agregando un flag para saber si tener los while:

```
boolean stop = false;
do{

    do{
        if(){
           stop = true;
        }
    }while(!stop); 
}while(!stop);
```

En este caso si stop pasa a `false`, se detendran ambos `while`.

Answer (score 1):

Basándome en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/886979/4955425) del famoso Jon Skeet, puedes asignarle un nombre al ciclo externo, y usar `break` para escapar fuera del ciclo externo:

```
void Metodo() {
    // mas código

    ciclo_externo:           // le asignas un nombre al ciclo aquí
    do{
        do{
            if(){
                // esto te saca de ambos ciclos de una vez.
                break ciclo_externo; 
            }
        }while(); 
    }while();

    // mas código
}
```

O, probablemente la mejor opción es de mover los 2 ciclos a un método distinto para que puedas usar `return` sin problema:

```
void Metodo() {
    // mas código

    ejecutarCiclos();

    // mas código
}

void ejecutarCiclos() {
    do{
        do{
            if(){
                return; 
            }
        }while(); 
    }while();
}
```

Comment: Me parece buena idea lo de crear un método nuevo, gracias